# Линковка .dll имея .h MinGW C++

Tags: c++, dll, mingw

есть в наличии динамическая библиотека (.dll) и ее заголовок (.h). В своем коде подключаю заголовок, через include, пытаюсь это все собрать через mingw, используя команду g++ main.cpp lib.dll lib.h, но получаю undefined reference.
Как правильно линковать динамические библиотеки в случае отсутствия .a/.lib?

Comment: `lib.h` в команде явно указывать не нужно. Насколько новый у вас mingw? Свежие версии точно умеют с .dll линковаться.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat mingw730_32. А отсутствие lib.h не помогло

Comment: У меня работает, gcc 8.3.0 х64 из msys2. Уверены, что в .dll нужная функция есть? `objdump`ом проверяли?

Answer (score 1):

Если библиотека и заголовочный файл находятся в одном каталоге с исходником

```
g++ -L. -I. main.cpp -llib
```

И кстати, не очень удачное название для библиотеки, GCC автоматически подставляет префикс "lib" при поиске библиотек.

Comment: main.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `getFunction1[abi:cxx11]()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: `getFunction1` - это функция из заголовочного файла? lib.dll компилировалась тем же компилятором?

Comment: Да, это функция из заголовочного файла. По поводу компилятора - неизвестно =(

Comment: В выдаче `nm -g lib.dll` есть эта функция?

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, она там с немного измененным именем

Comment: Похоже на несовместимость ABI. Можно попробовать добавить параметры `-std=c++11` и `-fabi-version=11`, но не уверен, что поможет.